# Which is one best for dataTable

Tags: html, json, twitter-bootstrap

I want data Table plugin.

I am getting the value from server which is json obj by the jQuery ajax.

In that, i have object which contains all data.

I have to show these details in Data Table. So which plugin is best to use and feature.

Suggest me best plugin for Data table.

Answer (score 0):

you can download from here.. Best plugin for data tables.
https://datatables.net/download/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jqgrid](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html), it has very good features.And you will get good support in stackoverflow for this.

Answer (score 0):

have a look [here](http://www.datatables.net/blog/Twitter_Bootstrap_2), Twitter_Bootstrap_2 datatable.. it havig a lot of features..